# How can i get partitioned script using get_ddl?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, partitioning

I am using Oracle 12c as database and getting ddl of table or other objects using :-

```
dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','TABLE_NAME','SCHEMA_NAME');
```

Same as for constraints and reference constraint i am using :-

```
dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('CONSTRAINT','TABLE_NAME','SCHEMA_NAME');
dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('REF_CONSTRAINT','TABLE_NAME','SCHEMA_NAME');
```

Now my problem is i want to extract partition script from table and i tried following :-

**`select dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('PARTITIONING','TABLE_NAME','SCHEMA_NAME') from dual;`**

but its giving the following error :-

```
ORA-31600: invalid input value PARTITIONING for parameter OBJECT_TYPE in function GET_DEPENDENT_DDL
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 6069
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 8761
ORA-06512: at line 1
31600. 00000 -  "invalid input value %s for parameter %s in function %s"
*Cause:    A NULL or invalid value was supplied for the parameter.
*Action:   Correct the input value and try the call again.
```

I have also tried :-

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PARTITION','PARTITION_NAME','SECONDARYUSER') from dual;
```

but its giving same error.

**Please suggest how can i get partitioned ddl using get_ddl method in oracle.**

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is a table option, not a separate object.  By default, `GET_DDL` for a table should produce the partitioning information.  If it doesn't, it's possible you have a session transformation that's disabling it.  These two statements should definitely generate a DDL script that includes all the partitioning options:

```
begin
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform,'PARTITIONING',true);
end;
/

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','TABLE_NAME','SCHEMA_NAME') from dual;
```

If you're looking for a way to automatically generate a script that converts a table from nonpartitioned to partitioned, I'm afraid you're out of luck.  Although 12c has the ability to convert tables with `ALTER TABLE`, the package `DBMS_METADATA_DIFF` apparently has not yet been updated to understand those commands.

For example, if you create the same table with and without partitions, this script doesn't work:

```
select dbms_metadata_diff.compare_alter(object_type => 'TABLE', name1 => 'TABLE2', name2 => 'TABLE1') diffs from dual;

DIFFS
--------------------------------------------------------------
-- ORA-39266: Cannot alter unpartitioned table to partitioned.
  ALTER TABLE "JHELLER"."TABLE2" RENAME TO "TABLE1"
```

Luckily, in some cases the `ALTER` syntax seems easy.  In my simple examples, I could change a table to partitioned with a command like this:

```
alter table unpartitioned_table modify
[partitioning clause]
online;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to filter transformation option :-

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
   DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
   DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false);
   DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'STORAGE', false);
END;
/

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('TABLE', table_name, owner)
FROM   all_tables
WHERE  owner      = UPPER('REFDATA')
AND    table_name = DECODE(UPPER('<TBL_NM>'), 'ALL', table_name, UPPER('<TBL_NM>'));
```

This should give only the default partition along with table ddl.